# Ruby condition to increment one variable or the other

Tags: ruby, ternary-operator, code-formatting

Lets say I have to variables in Ruby for a little game

```
times_won # Any integer
times_lost # Any integer
```

and the result of the last round

```
result # string, can be: "won", "lost" or "drawn"
```

What would be a nicer way of doing this

```
times_won += 1 if result == "won"
times_lost += 1 if result == "lost"
```

I'm trying with ternary operator but I dont know how to use it with multiple variables. Also a case statement isn't much nicer.

Maybe anyone knows a one-liner to blow my mind.

**EDIT:**

Where is the Error in a nested ternary operator like this?

```
 times_won,times_lost += result == 'drawn'  ? [0,0] : result =='won' ? [1,0] : [0,1]
```

Comment: Even if your last line worked, would you understand it without an additional comment?

Comment: Well, maybe not without thinking about it some time, but my main intrest here is to learn new things in ruby.

Comment: You might consider dropping the variable `times_lost`: `games_played += 1; times_won += 1 if result == "won"`. Then just compute the number of losses as needed. Yes, there are still two statements, as there should be.

Comment: A now-deleted post showed how `eval` could be used to meet your requirement. As you commented, "this is nice", I fell compelled to say that "this is bizarre" would have been more apt. Never in a million years would you see `eval`used that way.I'm not even sure it was meant as a serious answer.

Comment: The error in a nested ternary is you just made your code less readable, which translates to less maintainable, which translates to more likely to result in a bug. Don't do that. The *ONLY* time to use a ternary is when it results in simplified code which then reduces the other two concerns. In Perl we'd use long ternaries but Ruby isn't Perl.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a hash:

```
@counter = {won: 0, lost: 0, drawn: 0}
result = :won

@counter[result] += 1

@counter
#=> {:won=>1, :lost=>0, :drawn=>0}
```

I've used symbols as keys, but it also works with string.

If other parts of your code rely on `times_won` and `times_lost`, you could implement them as methods:

```
def times_won
  @counter[:won]
end
```

**Regarding your edit**

Mixing [abbreviated assignment](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Abbreviated+Assignment) and [multiple assignment](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Multiple+Assignment) doesn't work:

```
a, b += 1, 2 #=> SyntaxError
```

You have to specify the calculation explicitly:

```
a, b = a + 1, b + 2 # increments `a` by 1 and `b` by 2
```

And of course you can replace the fixed values with a more complex expression:

```
a, b = a + (result == 'won' ? 1 : 0), b + (result == 'lost' ? 1 : 0)
```